# Content from TinyMce and Bootstrap

Tags: php, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, tinymce

I want to use the html Content generated by TinyMCE in a Bootstrap environment, but Bootstrap is overwirting the styles given from the TinyMCE editor.

is there a way to disable all bootstrap classes within a `"<div>"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the same issue in the same context. Here is my code

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea#myarea"
    });
</script>
```

---

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
        <textarea id="myarea" name="myarea"><?php echo(stripslashes(html_entity_decode($myarea))); ?></textarea>
    </div>
```

PHP : once the text has been typed, I submit it via PHP and it goes through these functions before being saved in a database.

```
htmlspecialchars($myarea);
trim($myarea);
addslashes($myarea);
```

---

Send some code if you'd like a more customed answer though.

Comment: I don't have trouble with the Editor itself.
The problem is "rendering" the Content in the frontend of my CMS, I need something like : "<div class="nobootstrap">$tinymceoutput</div>"